# Clarification on MVC Architecture Overview

Tags: c#, architecture, mvc, asp.net

I'm doing an MVC 4 architecture diagram for a report and since I'm relatively new to MVC,i was wondering could some one clarify with me is REST (HTTPPOST etc) between view and controller, or controller to model? also should model drawn as in the server side and view + controller on client side?

here a few of my mock ups atm

[image: Diagram 1]

---

[image: Architectural overview of Job Tracking System]

Comment: In your first diagram, the REST block should be on the server, not the client.  I assume that you're using a client-side binding framework like Angular there.

Comment: yes i am using angular, so basically move all over to the server side except for the view?

Comment: No, just the REST block.  It's in the wrong place.  The REST interface will provide data to the controller on the client side.

Comment: Thank you @RobertHarvey :) i have one small question just when we are on the topic of angular.js, what is the default REST service used in a defaulf MVC4 project?

Comment: Actually, what you want that block to be is a *Service Layer,* which implements REST as its communication model.

Comment: What do you mean by "default REST service?"  It's a service that provides data via a REST interface; you can build it any way you want.  But it resides on the server, not the client.

Comment: say i went to start a new ASP.NET MVC4 project on VS2012, what REST interface/service does it use out of the box is what i mean.

Comment: The one which you build into your ASP.NET MVC4 project, probably using [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: thank you @RobertHarvey! I appreciate your information :) gives me a better picture of MVC and its architecture :)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there...

Putting the REST between the view and the controller would be the right choice. That means that your view, i.e. a `javascript` code, will send `REST` calls to your server, which process those calls in the appropriate controller (then the models and etc.). In addition this controller would be responsible for the `response` back to the client.

I believe you have a confusion with the controller's part in the system. **Depending on your implementation and application frameworks you're using**, the controller should be part of your 'server' layer, which tells which and what view to call/dispatch.

Take a look at the following (simple) diagram:

[image]

The controller is responsible for updating the view, and maybe showing you another view.
For example, consider the following scenario:

1. The user fills out a form and submits it
2. Server validates the form and

   2.1. If it is valid - the controller will route you to a "thank you" view

   2.2. else the controller will route you to a "missing input" view
3. The user gets the routed view as a response.

Comment: The third sentence of your answer ("The controller should be part of your 'server' layer, which tells which and what view to call/dispatch.") is the only one that adds anything new.  The OP's existing diagram already correctly illustrates the MVC relationships.

Comment: Also, the controller might actually reside on the client; it depends on the architecture.  If this is a SPA application, the controller resides in a client-side Javascript library like [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller), and the server will provide data to it through a REST interface.

Comment: @RobertHarvey regarding your first one, no prob i'll edit to clarify, also I see another hidden question there. Regarding your second comment, Angular more like MVVM (Model, View, ViewModel) more than MVC (even if claimed otherwise). Hence, the way you code Angular is quite "enhanced MVC" :)

Comment: Well, now that we're splitting hairs, MVC (as practiced by web developers) isn't quite the same MVC that was invented 30 years ago in Smalltalk, and MVVM is regarded as an evolution of MVC anyway.

Comment: Your edit is wrong.  The OP has established that they're using Angular, and the REST block doesn't go on the client, certainly not between the controller and the view.  You're still thinking the controller resides on the server; it doesn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - sorry it was not mentioned on the post itself but in the comments between you and the post owner. I wasn't aware